# What is the convention when using Boto3 clients vs resources?

Tags: amazon-web-services, resources, client, boto3

So I have an API that makes calls to AWS services and I am using Boto3 in order to do this within my python application. The question I have deals with Boto3's client vs resource access levels. I think I understand the difference between them (one is low-level access the other is higher-level object-oriented service access) but my question is if it is okay to instantiate *both* a client and resource? For example, some resource functionality is easier to access using a resource over a client, but there is some functionality only the client has. Is it bad to instantiate both and use the easiest access level when needed or will there be some sort of disconnect when using two separate access levels when connecting to the same resource?

I am not running into any errors with my code to connect to SQS shown below, however I want to make sure that down the line I am not shooting myself in the foot by arbitrarily choosing between the client/resource for the same aws connection.

```py
import boto3

REGION = 'us-east-1'

sqs_r = boto3.resource('sqs', REGION)
sqs_c = boto3.client('sqs', REGION)

def create_queue(queue_name):
    queue_attributes = {
        'FifoQueue': 'true',
        'DelaySeconds': '0',
        'MessageRetentionPeriod': '900', # 15 minutes to complete a command, else deleted.
        'ContentBasedDeduplication': 'true'
    }

    try: 
        queue = sqs_r.get_queue_by_name(QueueName=queue_name)
    except:
        queue = sqs_r.create_queue(QueueName=queue_name, Attributes=queue_attributes)


def list_all_queues(queue_name_prefix=''):
    all_queues = sqs_c.list_queues(QueueNamePrefix=queue_name_prefix)    
    print(all_queues['QueueUrls'])
    print(type(all_queues))
```

Both of the above function work properly, one creates a queue and the other lists all of the queues at sqs. However, one function uses a resource and the other uses a client. Is this okay?

Comment: Use which ever method you like. It is just two different interfaces for accomplishing the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can certainly use both.

The **resource** method actually uses the **client** method behind-the-scenes, so AWS only sees client-like calls.

In fact, the resource even *contains* a client. You can access it like this:

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
copy_source = {
    'Bucket': 'mybucket',
    'Key': 'mykey'
}
s3.meta.client.copy(copy_source, 'otherbucket', 'otherkey')
```

This example is from the boto3 documentation. It shows how a `client` is being extracted from a `resource`, and makes a `client` call, effectively identical to `s3_client.copy()`.

Both client and resource just create a local object. There is no back-end activity involved.